# Proper way to run docker container using Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When making a jenkinsfile, I have steps to run dockers image which pulling from my docker hub.

```
stage('pull image and run') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                docker login -u <username> -p <password>
                docker run -d -p 9090:3000 <tag>
                '''
            }
        }
```

This step is okay if I run this script the first time. However, if I run this script the second time, it will get this error.

```
Login Succeeded
+ docker run -d -p 9090:3000 <tag>
669955464d74f9b5186b437b7127ca0a24f6ea366f3a903c673489bec741cf78
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint distracted_driscoll (db16abd899cf0cbd4f26cf712b1eee4ace5b491e061e2e31795c2669296068eb): Bind for 0.0.0.0:9090 failed: port is already allocated.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 125
Finished: FAILURE
```

Obviously, the port 9090 is not available so the execution failed.

### Question:

What is the correct way to upgrade an app inside a docker container?
I can stop the container before running the `docker run`, but I can't find a proper way to do that in jenkinsfile steps.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You should look into using the Jenkins Pipeline plugin for docker, as that will automatically stop the container once the code exits the block. If you use manual CLI commands within shell step methods like you are currently doing, then you will need to cleanup the container yourself afterward, so that e.g. the port becomes free.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has really good docker support to make your build proceed within docker container. good example can be found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)

One declarative example to do maven build will be:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
       docker {
         image 'maven:3-alpine'
         args  '-v /tmp:/tmp'
         registryUrl 'https://myregistry.com/'
         registryCredentialsId 'myPredefinedCredentialsInJenkins'
       }  
    }
    
    stages {
        stage("01") {
            steps {
                sh "mvn -v"
            }
        }
        stage("02") {
            steps {
                sh "mvn --help"
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

In a scripted pipeline, it would be

```
node {
  docker.withRegistry('https://registry.example.com', 'credentials-id') {
     docker.image('node:14-alpine').inside("-v /tmp:/tmp") {
        stage('Test') {
            sh 'node --version'
        }
     }
  }
}
```